# Does any such function exist given the following conditions

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, step-function

I would like to know if a step function $f$ exists on $\mathbb{R^+}$ such that for $k \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$f(0)=1$$
$$f(1)=0$$
$$f(2k) = (-1)^k$$
$$f(2k+1) = 0$$

Where $f(x) \not= \cos\bigl(\frac{\pi x}{2}\bigr)$

If so, I would appreciate a specific example of such a function that can be expressed in standard mathematical notation. I would also not like anything in forms of trigonometric functions.

Comment: Yes. There are infinitely many such functions. Consider $$f(x)=\cos{\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)}+\sin{(\pi x)}$$

Comment: Correct, yea, but I feel like I’m looking for a step funct Of some sort. I’ll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

As per the conditions : f(1) cannot be defined.  Do you need functions f(x)  that satisfy the above conditions and  are undefined for x=1 ?

Comment: Ah you’re right, I fixed it. I want f(1)=0. Thanks for that

Comment: If you are looking for a step function: [cos(πx/2)] should do.

Comment: Just out of curiosity : if you could share your reason as to why you are looking for such a function : (may be you need to plug in such a function somewhere)  one can be more helpful.

Comment: Alright, will edit now: